# File upload and download with Digilocker

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, plugins, sdk

I want to perform file upload and download operation with Degilocker in  spring boot application
how will i done the upload and download operation ?

I have researched about any SDK for the make connection with Degilocker and perform the operation file upload and download but i didn't found any sdk
OR any java example for the file upload and download.